# Use a single TextBlock for displaying error message?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

The idea is, I want to show a single error at the bottom of the window, but the source of an error can be several elements like TextBoxes.

I have succesfully created a validation of a single field, yet i struggle to achieve my new goal.

Based on internet tutorials, i have created `ValidationRule` which only checks if a entered text is empty. Then added `ErrorConverter:IValueConverter` which translates the error to string. On the XAML part i have a validation rule bound to 2 TextBoxes

```
<TextBox.Text>
    <Binding ElementName="Self" Path="MyProperty" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" NotifyOnValidationError="True">
        <Binding.ValidationRules>
            <local:ValidateEmpty />
        </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
</TextBox.Text>
```

and one TextBox for displaying error

```
Text="{Binding ElementName=myElement,
      Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem,
      Converter={StaticResource ErrorConverter}
```

I have all the needed `DependencyProperties`. The problem is, error textbox can only be bound to one component at a time (`myElement` in my example), if i change the `ElementName` to my grid name or anything else, nothing happens, no error message is shown.

So what should i do be able to "capture" errors from multiple components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest two different ways of doing that:

**1st way: ViewModel-side validation**

If your `ViewModel` implements `IDataErrorInfo` to define errors in the inputs, then you must have a `string Error` in your class. 
This string is actually here for the exact thing you're looking to do: Having a single justification for multiple errors.

Here is my way of implementing it:

```
    public string Error
    {
        get { return PerformValidation(string.Empty); }
    }

    public virtual string this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            return PerformValidation(propertyName);
        }
    }
```

My `PerformValidation` method is virtual, to be overridden in the inheriting classes. But here is what it would look like:

```
    protected override void PerformValidation(string propertyName = null)
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName) || propertyName == "Property1")
        { }
        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName) || propertyName == "Property2")
        { }
        //...
    }
```

Then, my `TextBlock` is simply bound to the `Error` string which would always show the first encountered error

**2nd way: UI-ValidationRule side**

Alternatively, you can simply use a `MultiBinding`, or simply a `TextBlock` containing `Run` objects.
Simple example:

```
        <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center">
             <Run Text="{Binding ElementName=myElement,
                         Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem,
                         Converter={StaticResource ErrorConverter}}" />
             <Run Text="{Binding ElementName=myElement2,
                         Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem,
                         Converter={StaticResource ErrorConverter}}" />
             <Run Text="{Binding ElementName=myElement3,
                         Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem,
                         Converter={StaticResource ErrorConverter}}" />
        </TextBlock>
```

And just add one `Run` per Element

Comment: I chose the 2nd way and it was just plain awesome, super simple solution. There was one addition which was required to make it work. I had to add binding mode `Mode=OneWay` as it is accessing a read-only property `(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem`. Thank you